# in R how to get error messages in english

Tags: r, bioconductor

I am trying some tutorials on bioconductor; but I get error messages, that I would like to search/submit; unfortunately, since R is installed on a system configured in french, R returns me messages in french; how could I have these messages in english.

My system: 
Ubuntu 10.04 runing gnome 3;
R version is the last (2.15.1)
Bioconductor have been updated to 2.10,

and I try to download/use datasets GSE20986 (but I have had a similar error with another dataset GSE2034, while following the procedure given in "R in a nutshell"); to those of you speaking french the error message that I get is:

```
> getGEOSuppFiles("GSE20986")
[1] "ftp://ftp.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pub/geo/DATA/supplementary/series/GSE20986/"
Erreur dans scan(file, what, nmax, sep, dec, quote, skip, nlines, na.strings,  : 
  la ligne 1 n'avait pas 6 éléments
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Well, `Sys.setenv(LANGUAGE="fr")` makes my errors print in French.  I thought `Sys.setenv(LANGUAGE='en')` would make them print in English, but it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Here's a [blog post](http://mito.air-nifty.com/mitoakiyoshiblog/2010/03/how-to-change-l.html) that may help

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you need to set the `LANGUAGE` environment variable when you start **R**.  try starting **R** like this:

```
$ LANGUAGE=en R
```

Comment: To make it permanent, add `export LANGUAGE=en` to your `~/.bashrc`.

Answer (score 4):

In general, on linux, try at the command line

```
locale -a
```

to get a list of locales, maybe you want en_US.utf8, and then

```
LC_ALL=en_US.utf8 R
```

but it's often better to opt for "C" locale, which is plain old text.

```
LC_ALL=C R
```

In an R session, `Sys.setlocale("LC_ALL", "en_US.utf8")` or other components from `Sys.getlocale()` and the locales supported on your system and reported from `locale -a`.

Answer (score 2):

For me worked in `R`:

```
Sys.setlocale("LC_MESSAGES", "C")
```

Ubuntu 16.04
R version 3.4.3 (2017-11-30) -- "Kite-Eating Tree"

Also for me `Sys.setenv(LANGUAGE='en')` did not work.