# R language setting can't be change with "default writes" command on mac

Tags: r, macos, locale

I'm a mac user and want to change R locale to English.

I know `defaults write` should set R's locale on osx. But, strangely, the command doesn't work.

```
defaults write org.R-project.R force.LANG en_US.UTF-8
```

When I launch R by executing R.app, English messages are properly shown, but Terminal.app shows Japanese messages:

[image: R.app]
[image: Terminal.app]

My Environment is as follows:

- Mac OS 10.8.5
- R version 3.0.1 (2013-05-16) -- "Good Sport" Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin10.8.0 (64-bit)

Result of `sessionInfo()` on Terminal:

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 3.0.1 (2013-05-16)
Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin10.8.0 (64-bit)

locale:
[1] ja_JP.UTF-8/ja_JP.UTF-8/ja_JP.UTF-8/C/ja_JP.UTF-8/ja_JP.UTF-8

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base
```

On R.app:

```
R version 3.0.1 (2013-05-16)
Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin10.8.0 (64-bit)

locale:
[1] en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/C/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base    

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] caret_5.17-7    grid_3.0.1      kernlab_0.9-18  lattice_0.20-15
```

Comment: What is the output of `sessionInfo()` in both cases?

Comment: @Dason Thank you. I put the output of sessionInfo() [here](http://pastebin.com/ZzGXeLbb).

Comment: See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12642651/in-r-how-to-get-error-messages-in-english), for both answer as well as Paul Hiemstra's comment: basically instead of calling `r` in the terminal you can call `LC_ALL=en_GB r` for instance and you can make it permanent by adding it to the `~/.bashrc` file. Your `defaults write...` solution indeed affect only R.app.

Comment: `Language=en R` works perfectly! Thank you, @plannapus.

Comment: @plannapus or put it in `.Renviron` to affect R everywhere

Comment: @handley Great. I love the way you mentioned. Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As @plannapus wrote, starting R with `Language=en R` works well in my environment. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12642651/in-r-how-to-get-error-messages-in-english).

Thank you for your help.

---

**edit (2013/11/8)**

According to gentle community replies, there seems to be several solutions. As for me, both of these ways works well.

1. Launching R console with specifying language as `Language=en R` (already mentioned previous post)
2. Set environment variable by adding just one line `Language=en R` to ~/.Renviron

Comment: For future reference, `R` questions which are specific to OS X can be submitted to the r-sig-mac mailing list.  The folks there are quite knowledgeable about stuff like this.

Comment: @Carl r-sig-mac looks great. I'll subscribe it. Thank you.