# How to ensure english error messages in testthat unit tests

Tags: r, locale, testthat

I have a lot of unit tests using the `testthat` package that expect english error messages.

If other developer run the tests on a computer configured for a non-english locale the error message are emitted in a different language and my tests fail.

How can I initialize testthat to change the language settings only during the test run-time without manually or permanently changing the language or test environment from outside of R (like e. g. proposed here: [in R how to get error messages in english](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12642651/4468078))?

```
library(testthat)
# works only in english locales...
expect_error(log("a"), "non-numeric argument to mathematical function", fixed = TRUE)
```

**Edit 1:** Changing the locale during run-time does not change the language of the error messages (using Ubuntu and OSX High Sierra):

```
Sys.setlocale( locale = "en_US.UTF-8")
Sys.getlocale()  # en_US is active now but messages are still in another language
```

**Edit 2:** It seems that `Sys.setenv("LANGUAGE"="EN")` seems to change the error message language immediately (tested using OSX). Where should I put this command for testthat? In the testthat.R file?

[The R console is in German language, how can I set R to English?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28171235/4468078)

**Edit 3:** As a first work-around I have put

```
Sys.setenv("LANGUAGE"="EN")  # work-around to always create english R (error) messages
```

into my `testthat.R` file under the tests folder (it seems to work but I am not sure whether this is the right or best way...

Answer (score 3):

Setting `Sys.setenv("LANGUAGE" = "EN")` works for me as well.

However, when testing with `devtools::test()` - as ctrl + shift + T in Rstudio will do - I had to call `Sys.setenv()` in the test scripts inside the *tests/testthat/* directory. The reason being that `devtools::test()` will call `testthat::test_dir()` circumventing the *tests/testthat.R* file.

So far, this did not have undesirable side-effects. The environment variable will only be set for that particular R process as described in the [help page](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/Sys.setenv.html):

> Sys.setenv sets environment variables (for other processes called from within R or future calls to Sys.getenv from this R process).

For completeness, you can also unset the variable again **on Windows** (see comments).

```
  Sys.setenv("LANGUAGE" = "DE")
  expect_error(log("a"), "Nicht-numerisches Argument")
  Sys.setenv("LANGUAGE" = "FR")
  expect_error(log("a"), "argument non numérique ")
  Sys.unsetenv("LANGUAGE")
```

RStudio might also give trouble (I was not able to change the language there interactively), but when executing with `devtools::test()` it works.

Finally, wrapping it in a helper function.

```
expect_error_lang <- function(..., lang = "EN") {
    Sys.setenv("LANGUAGE" = lang)
    expect_error(...)
    Sys.unsetenv("LANGUAGE")
  }
#...
expect_error_lang(log("a"), "non-numeric")
expect_error_lang(log("a"), "Nicht-numerisches", lang = "DE")
expect_error_lang(log("a"), "argument non", lang = "FR")
```

Comment: Which OS are you using?

Comment: @RYoda That was on Windows 7. I just tried it on Linux Mint 18.2 and there this approach **fails**. I can set the language once using `Sys.setenv("LANGUAGE" = fr_fr)` but never unset it again until I relaunch the R session.

Comment: OK, thanks for trying, I am observing the same problems using Ubuntu 14.04 (cannot change the language reliably). BTW I like the idea of your wrapper function `expect_error_lang`!